# How can I use data returned in an Ajax POST call outside the return function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, global-variables

I have an Ajax POST call in jQuery that runs a PHP script and receives some data back. I want to be able to process that data outside the success function.

I have instantiated a global variable `components`, but this does not seem to have scope inside the success function.

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378769/how-can-i-get-access-to-the-data-returned-from-a-jquery-ajax-call-outside-the) I tried to call a function outside the AJAX call to assign the data to a global variable `components_passed`.  This also does not work.

How can I get the data into a global variable? I could just call a function to do what I want to do, but I may want to access the data again.

```
// Function to try to receive data
var components_passed;
function pass_out(data) {
    components_passed = data;
}

var components = [];    // create empty array for component list
if ($('#area').val) {   // if area contains a value and isn't zero (i.e. an area has been selected)
$.post("/basic/get_area_components.php"
    ,{area: $("#area").val()}
    ,function(data){ components = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(components);  // Show data in console - works
        pass_out(data);   // Call function to try and assign data to global variable
    });
}
console.log(components);  // Doesn't work - empty array

console.log(components_passed);  // Doesn't work - empty array
```

Comment: `After reading this` - read it again - nothing can give you synchronous results from an asynchronous function

Comment: no matter how many functions you pass it through, asynchronous results remain asynchronous

Comment: `read it again` Which bit specifically? I thought what I was doing was equivalent to the first answer, but I may have missed something.
Or should I be using a callback as per the second answer? I'm not familiar with that but may have to learn.

Comment: no, you're not. you're setting a global variable inside the callback, which is asynchronously called, but are trying to console.log it outside the asynchronous callback - the `pass_out` function is called from within the asynchronous callback as well, so the assignment that takes place in that, is also done asynchronously - and you try to console.log that variable outside the asynchronous callback as well

Answer (score 0):

your missing a little concept: [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) means Asynchronous.

think about what's happening in which order:

you declare variables, functions and so on..

then do the XHR request,

then log the variable `components`

then log `components_passed`

then nothing.

at a certain point after, the AJAX call will return, and then, and only then, your callback is executed, your returned data saved inside `components_passed`.

what you may want to do is wait for the call to return and then do whatever, for example logging. But at the moment `console.log(components_passed)`is called, the data has not been loaded yet; that's why your're printing an empty variable.

Comment: `what you may want to do is wait for the call to return` How would I go about doing that?

Comment: actually depends on how do you have to use the information, but in general you have to trigger something from the callback of the request

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous code can be tricky to deal with at first

You'll see, from the console.log statements the order in which things happen

```
function do_something(c) {
    // here, c is components
    // you can do things here with c
    console.log(4);
}

if ($('#area').val) {   // if area contains a value and isn't zero (i.e. an area has been selected)
    console.log(1);
    $.post("/basic/get_area_components.php", {area: $("#area").val()}, function(data){ 
        console.log(3); // this line is executed once $.post has retrieved the data
        var components = JSON.parse(data);

        // everything you need to do with components, you must do here, or in functions called from here

        do_something(components);

    });
    console.log(2); // as you can see, this line is executed before the callback
}
```

Comment: This is a useful way to understand the situation. Could you clarify what you mean by "c is components"? Since you say "everything you need to do with components, you must do here" in the success function, presumably it's not actually "components".